# Can't get my type attribute set in my Profile model for STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `User` model which `has_one :profile`, and the `profile` model has a `type` column for Single Table Inheritance. I want a user to set `type` upon signing up, and I'm having trouble doing this.

i'm trying this in my profiles controller:

```
def create
   @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
   type = params[:user][:profile_attributes][:type]
   if type && ["Artist","Listener"].include?(type)
    @profile.update_attribute(:type,type)    
   end
end
```

and this in my form for the `User` new view:

```
<%= form_for(setup_user(@user)) do |f| %>
...
  <%= f.fields_for :profile do |t| %>
 <div class ="field">
    <%= t.label :type, "Are you an artist or listener?" %><br />
    <p> Artist: <%= t.radio_button :type, "Artist" %></p>
    <p> Listener: <%= t.radio_button :type, "Listener" %></p>
  </div>
  <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

and in my application helper:

```
def setup_user(user)
  user.tap do |u|
    u.build_profile if u.profile.nil?
  end
end
```

I can't seem to get `type` set when a User is created. It still defaults to `nil`. Why is this and how can I accomplish it? I'd appreciate a code example.

UPDATE:

This is the relevant code in my `User` model:

```
has_one :profile 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
before_create :build_profile
```

UPDATE 2: I get this error: `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: type`

Comment: Can you paste your model code in?

Comment: ok posted... and I also updated the code I'm using, so make sure to look over the question details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your create method with this one:

```
def create
  profile_type = params[:user][:profile][:type].constantize
  if ["Artist", "Listener"].include? profile_type
    @profile = current_user.profile = profile_type.new
    current_user.save!
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Profile type not supported"
  end
end
```

UPDATE: This is not really necessary. Useful code perhaps, but not necessary as a solution for the above problem.

Comment: `profile_type` would be the class itself, right? It wouldn't match strings.

Comment: Also, I'm still a weeee bit nervous about letting the user create a variable pointing to any arbitrary class before we filter. Granted, we aren't doing anything with them but checking equality, but it still gives me a funny feeling. I'd prefer doing the constantizing after the check, rather than before.

Comment: In chat, we have discovered some other underlying problems with the code structure, so once that is worked out, he ought to be set.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the object isn't being saved to the database. Try something like this:

```
def create
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  type = params[:user][:profile_attributes][:type]
  if type && ["Artist","Listener"].include?(type)
    @profile.update_attribute(:type,type)    
  end
end
```

Comment: `type` is still nil  O.o  I'm very confused

Comment: Make sure you aren't using `update_attributes` -- the `type` column is protected from mass assignment.

Comment: Check the log file -- does the UPDATE statement look correct?

Comment: ahh i got this error: `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: type`

Comment: I am using `update_attribute` for the create method, although I use `update_attributes` for the update profile method...

Comment: Either `update_attribute` or assigning the type attribute and calling `save` ought to work. Might also want to check that the form is creating the parameters correctly.

Comment: neither are working... this is really weird, I've tried both yours and Christopher's answers

Answer (score 1):

Your last issue can be resolved by adding

```
attr_accessible :type
```

Answer (score 1):

"type" is a protected attribute and you can't mass-assign a protected attribute.

The column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Try renaming the table column to something like "modelname_type".